# headless chrome in docker container, visit chrome://gpu , Error: vkCreateInstance failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER

Tags: docker, google-chrome, gpu, headless

I am trying to use GPU in chrome headless(version: Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61) mode in docker container.Bug get next Error:
exec cmd in container:
start container:
`docker run --gpus all --name centos-chrome-gpu1 -it centos-chrome-gpu:v1 /bin/bash`
exec cmd in container to detect gpu:

```
chrome --headless --no-sandbox --enable-features=Vulkan,UseSkiaRenderer --use-vulkan=native --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-logging --disable-vulkan-fallback-to-gl-for-testing --disable-vulkan-surface --use-angle=vulkan --print-to-pdf=out.pdf 'chrome://gpu'
```

got error:

```
[root@3298c3aaf37a data]# chrome --headless --no-sandbox --enable-features=Vulkan,UseSkiaRenderer --use-vulkan=native --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-logging --disable-vulkan-fallback-to-gl-for-testing --disable-vulkan-surface --use-angle=vulkan --print-to-pdf=out.pdf 'chrome://gpu'
[0529/064825.243304:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0529/064825.244022:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0529/064825.247593:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0529/064825.255679:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] RendererVk.cpp:127 (VerifyExtensionsPresent): Extension not supported: VK_KHR_surface
[0529/064825.256516:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] RendererVk.cpp:127 (VerifyExtensionsPresent): Extension not supported: VK_KHR_xcb_surface
[0529/064825.256673:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 0: Internal Vulkan error (-7): A requested extension is not supported, in ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/vulkan/RendererVk.cpp, initialize:1446.
[0529/064825.257420:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Internal Vulkan error (-7): A requested extension is not supported, in ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/vulkan/RendererVk.cpp, initialize:1446.
[0529/064825.257477:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize Vulkan failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0529/064825.257526:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[0529/064825.263608:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0529/064825.277845:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] RendererVk.cpp:127 (VerifyExtensionsPresent): Extension not supported: VK_KHR_surface
[0529/064825.277953:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] RendererVk.cpp:127 (VerifyExtensionsPresent): Extension not supported: VK_KHR_xcb_surface
[0529/064825.278040:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 0: Internal Vulkan error (-7): A requested extension is not supported, in ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/vulkan/RendererVk.cpp, initialize:1446.
[0529/064825.278129:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Internal Vulkan error (-7): A requested extension is not supported, in ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/vulkan/RendererVk.cpp, initialize:1446.
[0529/064825.278192:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize Vulkan failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0529/064825.278255:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[0529/064825.279831:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0529/064825.306604:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Warning: vkCreateInstance: Found no drivers!
Error: vkCreateInstance failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
    at CheckVkSuccessImpl (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/VulkanError.cpp:88)
    at CreateVkInstance (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:361)
    at Initialize (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:235)
    at Create (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:165)
    at operator() (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:420)
```

and gpu detect failed:

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
OpenGL: Disabled
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Raw Draw: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL2: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGPU: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
```

[err2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7dX.png)

Bug in host machine,it works well:

```
[root@ecs-aedd data]# chrome --headless --no-sandbox --enable-features=Vulkan,UseSkiaRenderer --use-vulkan=native --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-logging --disable-vulkan-fallback-to-gl-for-testing --disable-vulkan-surface --use-angle=vulkan --print-to-pdf=out.pdf 'chrome://gpu'
[0529/145105.116019:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0529/145105.892509:INFO:headless_shell.cc(660)] Written to file out.pdf.
```

and gpu detect is successful:

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Raw Draw: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Enabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
WebGPU: Hardware accelerated
```

[succ2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zda5L.png)

How should I do to solve this to detect successfully in container?

Comment: Can you please provide the content of the pictures as text?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Problen has updated and text is attached, thanks~

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, until I read [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/user-guide.html#user-guide) in detail.

I think you need to add `-e "NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all"` to mount drivers

Here is the command I use

```
sudo docker run \
  --runtime=nvidia --gpus all \
  -e "NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all" \
  -dt \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  browserless/chrome
```

[image]

I am using an AWS EC2 Machine

- Instance type: g4dn.xlarge
- SO: Ubuntu 20.04

Here the commands I ran to configure the host

```
# Install driver
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
export distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g')
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-drivers

# Install nvidia container toolkit
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
      && curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg \
      && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-container.list | \
            sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | \
            sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit

# Install docker
curl https://get.docker.com | sh \
  && sudo systemctl --now enable docker

# Configure nvidia runtime for docker
sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=docker
sudo systemctl restart docker

# Run your container
sudo docker run \
  --runtime=nvidia --gpus all \
  -e "NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all" \
  -dt \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  browserless/chrome
```

[Official Doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/index.html)